# manipulating a tag label with mink

Tags: php, selenium, testing, behat, mink

I would like to click on label corresponding to checkbox using mink php code. The code look like this:

```
<label class="label" for="somecheckbox_Id"> heylabel
 </label>
```

I can parse the checkbox for manipulation, can't parse the label. To parse the checkbox I did it like this

```
$doc= $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css','#somecheckbox_Id');
```

how can I access the corresponding label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels should always have a "for" attribute pointing to the checkbox in question. So, simply use

```
$page->find('css', 'label[for='+name+']');
```